# Typescript Declaration Merging Express Request Object and Passport.js User/Session

Tags: typescript, express, types, passport.js, typescript-typings

I am using passportjs middleware for authentication in an express/nodejs application.  I am getting errors about properties on my request.user object despite having followed the steps for [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

I have created a file at /types/index.d.ts in my project root, and added the following to my tsconfig.json

```
"typeRoots": [
  "/types/index.ts", "node_modules/@types"
]
```

My global declaration merge looks like this:

```
import { User } from "../users/user.interface";
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        user: User;
    }
  }
}
```

** UPDATE **
I have gotten the `req.user` object to stop throwing errors by changing my Declaration Merge to a Module Augmentation like so:

```
import { User } from "../users/user.interface";

declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
    interface Request {
        user: User;
    }
}
```

When referencing `request.session` object I get the following error: `Property 'session' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.`

Shouldn't passport's @types/passport types be merging with express's request object to add a session?

[image]

Does anyone know how I can successfully squash these errors / get TS to recognize this Declaration Merge.  I'm new to typescript and have been able to solve most of the issues I have come across but this one just keeps on surfacing.

Comment: The update helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend the `User` type used by Passport, you would merge your declarations into [`global.Express.User`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f9f7cf69213303e3c59eeeeb066c603a2df202ad/types/passport/index.d.ts#L20):

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface User {
        /* declare your properties here */
    }
  }
}
```

The type definitions provided by [`@types/passport`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/passport) do not define `global.Express.Request#session`, that is defined by [`@types/express-session`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/express-session) [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f9f7cf69213303e3c59eeeeb066c603a2df202ad/types/express-session/index.d.ts#L20-L33).

Comment: Thank you @samthecodingman, I reinstalled the @types/express-session package and changed the import and that seems to be cleared up.  I had declared the merge like you posted here but that did not work.  Declaring it as a module augmentation of "express-serve-static-core" did work though.